# How to change location of wp-config.php to folder or 2 folders up?

Tags: security, wp-config

How to change location of wp-config.php to folder or 2 folders up?

I read somewhere its good to put it out of public_html but since im using subfolder then i need to put it 2 levels up.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't move the file because you'd have to change other files which include wp-config.php and these files will be overridden at your next update, but you can move the content of the file ( at least your credentials) to another file two levels up and include() this file in your wp-config.php 
This solution should be update save

Comment: Note that one of unobvious downsides of include-nested config is that it wrecks WP CLI, which relies on parsing config file as text to boot WP core.

Comment: Yes. Of course- save and safe! How to make it?